# Python typing: How to use Generic?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Consider the following example:

```
import typing

T = typing.TypeVar('T', bound=typing.Union[int, bool, str])

class Test(typing.Generic[T]):

    def __init__(self, v: T) -> None:
        self.v = v
        self.t = type(v)

    def parse(self, s: str) -> T:
        if self.t == int:
            return int(s, base=0)
        elif self.t == bool:
            return s.lower() != 'false'
        elif self.t == str:
            return s
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError()
```

mypy complains:

```
test.py:13: error: Incompatible return value type (got "int", expected "T")
test.py:15: error: Incompatible return value type (got "bool", expected "T")
test.py:17: error: Incompatible return value type (got "str", expected "T")
```

How do I rewrite the code so that mypy understands that T is in this case int/bool/str?

Comment: Try using `typing.cast`.  E.g. `return cast(t, int)`.  This tells `mypy` that I know that this is an `int`, even though you have no way of figuring it out.

Comment: @FrankYellin yeah, that would work, but casting somehow feels like a dirty workaround. I was hoping there might be a way to rephrase the if statements so that mypy understands that I am checking the value of T.

Comment: mypy isn't as smart as you want it to be.

Comment: what's your use case? for example, why do you have `self.t`?

Comment: @joel `v` stores a configuration value. `parse` parses a value which could come from a UI or a config file and could be written to `v`. The value of `v` can change during run time, but `type(v)` should not. I am using `self.t` instead of `type(v)` because (1) to make debugging easier in case someone accidentally writes an invalid type to `v` and (2) because I am assuming that accessing `self.t` is faster than calling `type(self.v)`.